# Is there a way to point the camera in the direction of a specific vector in Javafx8?

Tags: javafx-8

I've looked around for awhile and I can't seem to find a way to point a camera in a direction say [1, 2, 3] without calculating the angles between everything. I'm actually new to 3d graphics in general so I don't know if I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my answer to provide an example of how to manipulate the Affine transform
relative to current position in scene. Which is a very useful Transform for 3D space.

I will cover the basics with code, I do suggest you read up on Transformation Matrices.
This is a good [Tutorial](http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/) and cover everything in "layman's" terms.

So first define a few Callbacks for getting both rows and cols from the affine matrix:

```
public Affine affine = new Affine();

//Points: fwd, right, up   Point3D: pos

//Forward / look direction    
Callback<Transform, Point3D> forwardColCallback = (a) -> {
    return new Point3D(a.getMzx(), a.getMzy(), a.getMzz());
};
Callback<Transform, Point3D> forwardRowCallback = (a) -> {
    return new Point3D(a.getMxz(), a.getMyz(), a.getMzz());
};
// up direction
Callback<Transform, Point3D> upColCallback = (a) -> {
    return new Point3D(a.getMyx(), a.getMyy(), a.getMyz());
};
Callback<Transform, Point3D> upRowCallback = (a) -> {
    return new Point3D(a.getMxy(), a.getMyy(), a.getMzy());
};
// right direction
Callback<Transform, Point3D> rightColCallback = (a) -> {
    return new Point3D(a.getMxx(), a.getMxy(), a.getMxz());
};
Callback<Transform, Point3D> rightRowCallback = (a) -> {         
    return new Point3D(a.getMxx(), a.getMyx(), a.getMzx());
};
//position
Callback<Transform, Point3D> positionCallback = (a) ->{
    return new Point3D(a.getTx(), a.getTy(), a.getTz());
};

Point3D getForwardCol(){
    return forwardColCallback.call(getTransformableNode().getLocalToSceneTransform());
}
Point3D getForwardRow(){
    return forwardRowCallback.call(getTransformableNode().getLocalToSceneTransform());
}
Point3D getRightDirection(){
    return rightDirCallback.call(getTransformableNode().getLocalToSceneTransform());
}
Point3D getRightRow(){
    return rightRowCallback.call(getTransformableNode().getLocalToSceneTransform());
}
Point3D getUpCol(){
    return upColCallback.call(getTransformableNode().getLocalToSceneTransform());
}
Point3D getUpRow(){
    return upRowCallback.call(getTransformableNode().getLocalToSceneTransform());
}
Point3D getPosition(){
    return positionCallback.call(getTransformableNode().getLocalToSceneTransform());
}
```

Ok, Now lets build some methods to use those.

Translations:

```
private void moveForward() {      
    affine.setTx(getPosition().getX() + speed * getForwardRow().x);
    affine.setTy(getPosition().getY() + speed * getForwardRow().y);
    affine.setTz(getPosition().getZ() + speed * getForwardRow().z);
}

private void strafeLeft() {
    affine.setTx(getPosition().getX() + speed * -getRightRow().x);
    affine.setTy(getPosition().getY() + speed * -getRightRow().y);
    affine.setTz(getPosition().getZ() + speed * -getRightRow().z);
}

private void strafeRight() {
    affine.setTx(getPosition().getX() + speed * getRightRow().x);
    affine.setTy(getPosition().getY() + speed * getRightRow().y);
    affine.setTz(getPosition().getZ() + speed * getRightRow().z);
}

private void moveBack() {
    affine.setTx(getPosition().getX() + speed * -getForwardRow().x);
    affine.setTy(getPosition().getY() + speed * -getForwardRow().y);
    affine.setTz(getPosition().getZ() + speed * -getForwardRow().z);
}

private void moveUp() {
    affine.setTx(getPosition().getX() + speed * -getUpRow().x);
    affine.setTy(getPosition().getY() + speed * -getUpRow().y);
    affine.setTz(getPosition().getZ() + speed * -getUpRow().z);
}

private void moveDown() {
    affine.setTx(getPosition().getX() + speed * getUpRow().x);
    affine.setTy(getPosition().getY() + speed * getUpRow().y);
    affine.setTz(getPosition().getZ() + speed * getUpRow().z);
}
```

For Rotations you could do something like this by adding a Translate and the 3 respective Rotate transforms:

```
// mouse coordinates not implemented in this example     
// You would need to define them
    scene.setOnMousePressed(me->{    
        t.setX(getPosition().getX());
        t.setY(getPosition().getY());
        t.setZ(getPosition().getZ());

        affine.setToIdentity();

        rotateY.setAngle(
                MathUtils.clamp(((rotateY.getAngle() + moveDelta.getX() * (speed * 0.05)) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180, -360, 360)
        ); // horizontal                
        rotateX.setAngle(
                MathUtils.clamp(((rotateX.getAngle() - moveDelta.getY() * (speed * 0.05)) % 360 + 540) % 360 - 180, -90, 90)
        ); // vertical

        affine.prepend(t.createConcatenation(rotateY.createConcatenation(rotateX)));
     }
  );
```